# XMLHttpRequest response 'undefined' ... UNLESS alerting the variable 1st

Tags: browser, xmlhttprequest, alert

Bugger!

I am using an xmlhttprequest in javascript, calling a php page. The php page is only echoing a string.

When the xmlhttprequest hits 4 200, the response text is saved to a string. Also, the xmlhttprequest is in a function, and that function returns the response text.

THE ISSUE: the function is returning `undefined`, but I've circumvented the error by adding an `alert(string)`. The alert then states 'undefined' and the function passes the echoed value on return, AS string!

With Opera, Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer, only FF and IE populate the response text. Opera and Chrome don't work at all.

Code:

```
    function xmlhttpr(help,type,address)
    {
        var string;
        if ( help )
        {
            string = 'The xmlhttpr function:<br>params: (help,type,address) 
   <br>as<br>false/true,<br>get/post,<br>/addr.ess?h=elp';
           return string;
       }
       if ( !address )
       {
           string = 'Parameter missing in xmlhttpr(0,type,address)';
           return string;
       }
       if ( type == 0 )
       {
           type = 'GET';
        }
       if (type == 1 )
       {
            type = 'POST';
        }
       if ( window.XMLHttpRequest )
       {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
       else
       {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
      }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
       {
            //alert(this.readyState + ' ' + this.status);
            if ( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )
            {
                string = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open( type , address , true );
        xmlhttp.send();
        alert(string); //STINKY
        if ( string )
        {
            return string;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'Request failure';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest is also called AJAX and A stands for asynchronous, when you call `.send()` the request is issued to the server but the browser doesn't wait the request to finish, it jumps right to the next line which is `alert(string)` and because the request hasn't finished yet it's natural for it to be undefined.

All AJAX requests are asynchronous by nature which means the browser never waits for a request to finish before jumping to the next line after `.send`.

Now in your case it's hard to build your function so it's better to remove the function altogether and wherever you call that function instead just do the request and inside `onreadystatechanged` inside the `if` you have your string so do with it what you want to do (showing it to user , processing,whatever).

By the way there is synchronous XMLHttpRequest but it's deprecated and shouldn't be used because javascript code is naturally executed in one thread even UI code and you don't want to hang the buttons waiting for some request to server to finish.

So it worked in FF and IE ?!! it worked by coincidence because the request happened to finish and string happened to be populated.

Comment: @Blitterator don't mention it, I recommend you to read about browsers' event loop